# Why won't the for loop execute for more than 4 iterations?

Tags: bash, for

In the following script, the for loop only outputs till unph4. I tried to write the value of $coils directly but doesn't work as well. I tried other iteration values to see the maximum I am getting is 9 (does the iteration number have to be a single digit?)

```
coil=34;

bash_command = sprintf(['for ph in all/ph[1-$coil].nii\n' ...
'do\n' ...
'   base=`basename $ph`;\n' ...
'   dir=`dirname $ph`;\n' ...
'   mag=$dir/"mag"${base:2};\n' ...
'   unph="unph"${base:2};\n' ...
'   prelude -a $mag -p $ph -u $unph -n 12&\n' ...
'done\n' ...
'wait\n' ...
'gunzip -f unph*.gz\n']);

unix(bash_command);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `all/ph[1-34].nii` matches at most 4 files: `all/ph1.nii`, `all/ph2.nii`, `all/ph3.nii`, and `all/ph4.nii`.

In shell patterns, a construction of the form `[`char1`-`char2`]` matches the characters which sort between char1 and char2; so `[1-34]` matchs `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.

You may want to change the `for` loop to

```
for i in $(seq 1 $coil)
do
    ph=all/ph${i}.nii
    ...
done
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it is still not working. I have files from all/ph1.nii to all/ph34.nii. I am getting the error 'Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.' Not sure what that means. Can you please suggest anything else?

Comment: It *is* working -- that's an error message from your application `prelude`. It has nothing to do with the shell, or with Linux. I cannot possibly know what your application does, and what parameters and data it expects; you may want to ask on a specialized forum dedicated to the specific application.